# Problem writing database data in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I was trying to save data in csv file with the help of python . Though the data is saving it is showing some strange pattern when I run my code in terminal.
**this is my python code**

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="",  # your password
                     db="getinvolved")        # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor()
# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("SELECT name,phoneNo,email FROM getinvolved")
# print all the first cell of all the rows
dblist=cur.fetchall()
length=len(dblist)-1
lastRow=dblist[length]
print(lastRow[0],lastRow[1],lastRow[2])
fieldname={'name','phoneNo','email'}
with open("emailsend.csv","a") as csvfile:
    writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldname)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({
        "name":lastRow[0],
        "phoneNo":lastRow[1],
        "email":lastRow[2]
        })
```

**this is my csv file that is showing random pattern. And I am also getting an empty row each time I store my value in it.The header name is juggling itself **

```
name,phoneNo,email

asdsfd,9876543,abc@hotmail.com

phoneNo,email,name

9876543,abc@hotmail.com,asdsfd

email,phoneNo,name

abc@hotmail.com,9876543,asdsfd

email,phoneNo,name

abc@hotmail.com,9876543,asdsfd

name,phoneNo,email

asdsfd,9876543,abc@hotmail.com

name,email,phoneNo

asdsfd,abc@hotmail.com,9876543
```

**I want it to save my data like below, without any blank row each time I add a new value**

```
name,email,phoneNo
asdsfd,abc@hotmail.com,9876543
name,email,phoneNo
asdsfd,abc@hotmail.com,9876543
name,email,phoneNo
asdsfd,abc@hotmail.com,9876543
```

Comment: you may have `'\n'` at the end of email - you should `strip()` it: `"email": lastRow[2].strip()`

Comment: you should write list `writerow(lastRow[0:3])` instead of dictionary and then it will keep order.

Comment: maybe you should use list instead of set() in `fieldname= ['name','phoneNo','email']` because `set()` doesn't have to keep order.

Comment: to get last row you can use `dblist[-1]` and you don't have to use `len(dblist)-1`

Comment: When I use ```writerow(lastRow[0:3]) ```it is keeping it in order but I am still getting a blank row and ```strip() ```method is not working with tuple and even type conversion to string doesn't seem to work @furas

Comment: you have to use `strip()` with every element separatelly.

Comment: see doc [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) - it uses `newline=''` in `open('names.csv', 'w', newline='')` and it can be solution for empty lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) which is highly recommended for this purpose:

```
import pandas as pd  
import MySQLdb
import csv
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="",  # your password
                     db="getinvolved")        # name of the data base

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT name,phoneNo,email FROM getinvolved', con=db)
df.to_csv('emailsend.csv', index=False)
```

Refer to the documentation to format dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` creates `set()` (or `dict()`) which doesn't have to keep order of elements so it can change order of data in rows. Better uses list

```
fieldname = ['name', 'phoneNo', 'email']  # `list` instead of `set` `{}`
```

In some systems you may have to use `open(..., newline='')` to skip new lines

```
with open("emailsend.csv", "a", newline='') as csvfile
```

In documentation you can see it in example for [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and read about it in [cvs.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) and [note](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3)

Answer (score 0):

[`REFERENCE`](http://zetcode.com/python/csv/)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import csv

f = open('names.csv', 'w')

with f:

    fnames = ['first_name', 'last_name'] # USE LIST
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fnames)    

    writer.writeheader() # WRITE HEADER ONLY ONCE
    writer.writerow({'first_name' : 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name' : 'Robert', 'last_name': 'Brown'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name' : 'Julia', 'last_name': 'Griffin'})
```